# Power BI - struggling with a Sum with specific condidions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate the biggest vendor by the sum of net sales.
Here is a example of my dataset:

| Vendor | Net Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Vendor A | 100 |
| Vendor B | 100 |
| Vendor A | 50 |

As you can see, the Vendor A (150) sold more then the vendor B (100).

So i need to calculate a measure that gives me the sum of the net sales of the biggest vendor, in this case that would be vendor A.

How can i calculate this ?

*Example of what i want to see in the card:*

150 $ - Vendor A

Comment: `MAXX(SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[Vendor], "Net Sales", SUM(Table1[Net Sales])), [Net Sales])` - It will get you the highest net sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want to see in the card using that measure.

```
MaxVendor = 
VAR T1 = SUMMARIZE(SalesTable, SalesTable[Vendor], "Net Sales", SUM(SalesTable[Net Sales]))
VAR MaxSales = MAXX(T1, [Net Sales])
VAR MaxRecord = FILTER(T1, [Net Sales] = MaxSales)
RETURN
    MAXX(MaxRecord, [Net Sales]) & " $ - " & MAXX(MaxRecord, [Vendor])
```

[image]